# cannot add additional tab for popular Tag to product view

Tags: blocks, tabs, tags, product-page

can not add popular Tag block in magento tab on product page

```
            <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml">
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
                    <alias>description</alias>
                    <title>Description</title>
                    <block>catalog/product_view_description</block>
                    <template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template>
                </action>


                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
                    <alias>Tagsssss</alias>
                    <title>Tagssssss</title>
                    <block>tag/popular</block>
                    <template>tag/popular.phtm</template>
                </action>


                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
                    <alias>additional</alias>
                    <title>Additional Information</title>
                    <block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block>
                    <template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </block>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaibhan.your issue at template file extension it should be `.phtml` from `.phtm`

Comment: Gambling ...gambling everywhere for the sake of reputation lol

Comment: why cannot you use comments to say this simple thing @amit